# Libraries issues when cross compiling for ARM

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rasbperrypi, gcc, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to cross compile my project for my raspberry Pi 3 without success, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS . I have the following warning (which leads to an error) :

```
CMake Warning at kobuki/yocs_velocity_smoother/CMakeLists.txt.20 (add_library):
Cannot generate a safe linker search path for target
yocs_velocity_smoother_nodelet because files in some directories may
conflict with libraries in implicit directories:

  link library [libpthread.so] in /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib may be hidden by files in:
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Some of these libraries may not be found correctly
```

I have this Warning for all my packages and with `libdl.so` and `librt.so` too, it's generating those kind of errors :

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libnodeletlib.so: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's my `rostoolchain.cmake` :

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf)

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH
  /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/
  /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib)

set(LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
  /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/
  /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE BOTH)
```

I can't manage to tell CMake to look only for the libraries in `usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib` instead of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, which variables need to be set to do that ? Or is my `rostoolchain.cmake` incomplete/wrong ?

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE :**

See [#q296016](https://answers.ros.org/question/296016/how-to-cross-compile-for-raspberry-pi-3/) for a more detailed question about this issue (and cross compilation in general)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295233/libraries-issues-when-cross-compiling-for-arm/) by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3907 on 2018-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not a cross-compilation expert, but this:

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY BOTH)
```

seems weird to me. According to [the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY.html), that searches both `gnueabihf` paths *and* the hosts paths ..

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-06-25**:
You're right I updated it but I have a new issue now I edited the question

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-25**:
If I may suggest: please undo your edit and mark the question as answered if setting things to `ONLY` resolved it. Then post a new question about your new problem.

ROS Answers has a 1-to-1 ratio of Qs and As. At least, that is the idea. Let's keep it that way.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-06-25**:
Alright, I will post an other question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-25**:
Thanks. Could you post a link to it to keep things connected?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-06-25**:
Yes, will do once i'll post it